# How to force OpenGL 3 in Linux's Unreal Engine 4 Editor?

Tags: linux, opengl, unreal-engine4

I'm experiencing graphical artifacts within Unreal Engine 4 Editor on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04, Intel HD Graphics 520 - Mesa 13.0.4). Glitches are visible in the preview window, as seen on the image pasted below:

[Glitch example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aDzE.png)

I have the latest mesa drivers, installing Mesa 17.x.x is not an option, since they cause problems for the OS overall - problems with which I don't want to struggle (yet).

Running the engine with the `-opengl3` flag seems to have no effect whatsoever. Example run:

```
Engine/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor Absolute/Path/To.uproject -opengl3
```

Changing the Anti-Alias settings in **Settings->Scalability** does not make a difference as well.

Long story short, how can I tackle this problem? Is developing in UE4 on Linux without a dedicated graphics card possible?

Comment: To force the editor to use OpenGL 3, you can fake the available OpenGL version using Mesa's environment variables: MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.5  ./UE4Editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Project Settings, you can change which rendering tech you want. It's in either General Settings or Rendering, I forget which; search for OpenGL.

As to developing on and for an in-built graphics card - Unreal will probably complain a lot, and performance will probably suffer. I think the gpu is used extensively for materials, but honestly this isn't something I know a great deal about. It would be an interesting test. You should profile your game (the profileGPU console while in-game should give a ton of information).